# Dynamically show/hide a UIPickerView that was created using the interface builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I'm trying to create an iPad/iPhone app that dynamically creates menus depending on a JSON object that is returned from a RESTful API.  Specifically I'm trying to show/hide a UIPickerView that I created using the interface builder.  In the properties menu in the interface builder I checked the box "hidden" for that UIPickerView.  I used this [tutorial](http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.com/2012/09/uipickerview-tutorial.html) to create to UIPickerView.  I've set the delegate and data source to the View Controller using the interface builder.  I'd like to unhide/show the UIPickerView when a certain condition is met.  So far I've tried the following code:

```
 [self.choicePicker setHidden:NO];
 self.choicePicker.hidden = NO;
```

I usually build such object programmatically but I thought I'd try it this way.  I've looking through various stackoverflow posts and doing research but I can't seem to find something that works.  I'm new to programming in Objective C.  Thanks in advance any help is greatly appreciated.

.h file code

```
@interface slrpViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
 {

IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker_choice;

NSMutableArray *dataArray;
NSMutableData *receivedData;
 }

 @property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel *nameLabel;
 @property(nonatomic, retain) UIPickerView *choicePicker;
```

.m file code

```
-(void)buildChoicesMenu:(NSDictionary *)choiceDict{
//in this method we build the choices menu

[self.choicePicker setHidden:NO];
self.choicePicker.hidden = NO;
if (self.choicePicker) self.choicePicker.hidden = !self.choicePicker.hidden;
}
```

Comment: That should work. So would you post some code?

Comment: The buildChoicesMenu method will always set self.choicePicker.hidden to YES... Are you setting it to NO somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two **different** picker views defined. One a property `choicePicker` (and an implicit `_choicePicker` instance variable), and another instance variable `picker_choice`. It seems you have connected your `picker_choice` in interface builder, but are trying to modify the property. In fact, if you try to print `po self.choicePicker` in the debugger, you would get `nil`, because there is nothing filling it.

Either remove the instance variable, and connect your property in interface builder, or synthesize your property with your instance variable by doing so:

```
@syntesize choicePicker=picker_choice
```